# SQL WHERE clause for column of lists

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I specify a WHERE clause, so that it returns a row if there is an intersection between the column's value (list of strings) and another list of strings provided?
Something like:

```
SELECT id, names
FROM table
WHERE ANY(names) = ANY(('John', 'Alice', 'Bob'))
```

So if the value `names` column is, e.g. `['George', 'Bob']`, the row should be returned.

Comment: Comma separated list of string in a column is usually considered as a design flaw.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes, it's *almost always* a design flaw. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788

Comment: Would it be better to change that into a parsable string?

Comment: @CraigRinger "usually" is not far from "almost always" ;)

Comment: Just a doubt : what's the datatype of names ? It could be json, no ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really can't change your design (which I would recommand, as mentionned by Craig Ringer)

You may use regexp_split_to_array

```
 SELECT id, names
    from (
    SELECT 
          id,
          names,
          regexp_split_to_table(names, ', ') as splitted_value
    from <yourTable>) t
    where splitted_value in ('John', 'Alice', 'Bob')
    group by id, names;
```

or more complicated, with your sample

```
SELECT id, names
    from (
    SELECT 
          id,
          names,
          regexp_split_to_table(replace(replace(names, '[''', ''), ''']', ''), ''', ''') as splitted_value

    from <yourTable>) t
    where splitted_value in ('John', 'Alice', 'Bob')
    group by id, names;
```

Another ugly way, using some json functions (as your column datas look like json)

**"Detail"** : I'm not a postgresql expert, and less than all in json datas part. So there may be much better way to do this.

```
select id, names 
from
 (select 
    id, 
    names,
    replace(cast(json_array_elements(cast(replace(names, '''', '"') as json)) as text), '"', '') as elem
  from <yourTable>) t
where elem in ('George', 'Bob');
```

Comment: Good call, I didn't see the sample in the original post. What a ghastly way to represent data in a database.

Answer (score 3):

[You should really use arrays or a table of records for this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788).

You can work around your design by [splitting strings into arrays at runtime](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) and [using PostgreSQL's array features](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

```
SELECT id, names
FROM table
WHERE string_to_array(names, ',') && ARRAY['John', 'Alice', 'Bob'];
```

If your comma separated values have spaces, etc, you might want `regexp_split_to_array` instead of `string_to_array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your own function which will mimic MYSQL`s FIND_IN_SET

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_in_set(str text, strlist text)
RETURNS int AS $$
SELECT i
   FROM generate_subscripts(string_to_array($2,','),1) g(i)
  WHERE (string_to_array($2, ','))[i] = $1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 0
  LIMIT 1
$$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT;
```

http://okbob.blogspot.ro/2009/08/mysql-functions-for-postgresql.html